# How to declare a record with *any* arbitrary key

Tags: typescript

I want to make an object that can be indexed by some arbitrary object, something as so:

```
let obj: { [key: unknown]: string } = { }

obj[window] = "Some Value";
```

However, doing this causes two errors:

1. I can't create an object from a non-indexable type (this can be circumvented with the `any` type, but I prefer to avoid type circumvention)
2. I can't index an object with a non-indexable type (in this case, `window`).

[TypeScript Demo Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgLggbwgbQNYgJ5IK4B2GBUA7gQLpIDOYATgJYEDmEAvhALwrsBQvsOGlJMAJmQpcIAIgDKUALYgIANQCGwPCGkBuAfGFiyAOgCCMKHTABhKAXpRgoOpO7SA8mAAWIOqo1auvwAxnbUjiDGwFDMABSChgTipBQAlLyhBOGgUTHxBiJJJuaWNnYOTr5pvEA)

Comment: You can't do that because the JavaScript it generates wouldn't do what you want.  You can only really index into JS objects with strings or symbols.  `obj[window] = "SomeValue"` coerces `window` to a string and is equivalent to `obj[window.toString()] = "SomeValue"` so you might as well do that.  Maybe you're looking for [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?  But that's something else.  Does that fully address the question?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks! That does answer the question - I wasn't too sure about the working mapping of keys (I just presumed that they got hashed)